# Reset/Revoke Cognito MFA (Phone Number) through and update it through login

Tags: amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication, totp

I have gone through all the questions, but all are not matching exactly with my scenario.

Scenario:
Admin can reset the phone number of any user. After resetting/revoking the phone number, user will get logout (if already login), and then user will go through the login process. There, he will add his new number and will get verification code on the new number.
Actually, when admin set the contact number to null, it starts giving MFA error because of the "phone_number_verified" flag and I am unable to update this flag as I am doing with "phone_number" field. And if I don't remove the number and try to update the number, amplify sends the code on the previous number.

If I get success in deleting the "phone_number_verified" attribute as I am doing with "phone_number" attribute, I will be able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar scenario while working with **Cognito** user authentication. It is simply not possible to update the number. I have went through different solutions but all led to nothing. I also tried to contact AWS support center for the confirmation. In the start, they were giving points but after further discussions, they confirmed that verified phone numbers cannot be updated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you could create a new account with new phone number and merge the two accounts?